# How to get views for the Google Analytics Embed API Custom Components?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, requirejs

I tried to implement the code from this link

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/custom-components/

I downloaded the two files `view-selector2` and `date-range-selector`

and kept in my local files.

I modified

```
var accountSummaries = require(['','/path/to/account-summaries.js']);//line no:18 in view-selector.js
```

Now its loaded the js file.

But I am not getting the output as they shown in link.

Iam getting output like this

```
Under Processing 
Start Date  [textbox with date]
End Date  [textbox with date]
Start Date  [textbox with date]
End Date [textbox with date]
```

and Its  giving console errors like:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (view-selector2.js:111)
```

I struggled with require() from past 12 hours.

Can anyone say whats my problem and how to solve it?

any links to get the work done is more helpful... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Embed API custom component demos don't use RequireJS, they use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), so if you're trying to load dependencies with RequireJS, it won't work.

If you look at the code samples on that page, they show you the location of the built files, so you should just use those instead of the source files (I'm not sure where you got them).

```
<!-- Include the ViewSelector2 component script. -->
<script src="/public/javascript/embed-api/view-selector2.js"></script>

<!-- Include the DateRangeSelector component script. -->
<script src="/public/javascript/embed-api/date-range-selector.js"></script>
```

Try it again using the files in the public directory, and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you @Philip Walton for enlighting about browserify and I got that files from [GitHub](https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools/tree/master/assets/javascript/embed-api) .

Comment: I am confused by these pointing to local files, but nowhere in the tutorial do I see anywhere it mentions downloading a local library.

Comment: I am with @wapples on this. I can not for the life of me figure out where these local files are supposed to come from. Anyone figure this out? No wher in the docs does it say to download local dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solved my problem.

```
requirejs.config({
 baseUrl: '../path/to/javascript/embed-api/accounts/lib',
});
var accountSummaries = require(['./index']);
```

in view-selector2.js.

But sometimes its not loading properly. Anyway This might help anyone. Thanks All.